# Static_cast to a non base class of the dynamic type

Tags: c++

I have this program from an exercise, and I don't understand how the `static_cast` is working here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void f() const { cout << " A::f "; }
    virtual void g() { cout << " A::g "; }
    virtual A* n() { cout << " A::n "; return this; }
    virtual void t() { cout << " A::t "; }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    virtual void f() const { cout << " B::f "; }
    void g() { cout << " B::g "; A::n(); }
    A* n() { cout << " B::n "; return this; }
    void t() { cout << " B::t "; }
};

class C: public A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << " C::f "; }
    void g() const { cout << " C::g "; }
};

int main() {
    A* q2 = new B(); 
    A* q3 = new C();
    (static_cast<C*>(q2))->g(); cout << endl;
    (static_cast<C*>(q2))->t(); cout << endl;
    (static_cast<B*>(q3->n()))->f(); cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
 C::g 
 B::t 
 A::n  A::f
```

Can someone explain how it can take the function in `C` if `C` has never been constructed for the pointer `q2`? How does the `static_cast` work in this case?

Comment: it does not "work". Code can compile, and produce output that looks meaningful, but that does not imply that the code is ok.

Comment: It's not. At least not really because it's UB (Undefined Behavior) to cast e.g. `q2` into a `C*` and access it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know this is not a good practice, but this is the exercise and I'm trying to understand what's happening. How is this not a compile error?

Comment: this is not about good or bad practice. Your code is just wrong. Read about undefined behavior. When your code has undefined behavior then anything can happen, including that it appears to work, and the compiler is not mandated to diagnose it

Comment: what exactly is your exercise? You were given this code?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I was given this code and asked to write what the output will be printed

Comment: btw you should add the `override` specifier when you override a virtual function. It looks like you wanted to have some overriding when in fact there is not https://godbolt.org/z/5d6x8bav8

Comment: then there is no correct answer. Frankly the code is rubbish. THere is more than one issue that needs to be fixed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But if you run the code the output is always the same

Comment: @matteocamillo Undefined beahviour is well... undefined. It may also make your code always run the same. And someday, change for no reason, or when you change the platform, or the compiler or whatever. Legend says that even demons can fly out of your nose :p

Comment: if this code was given to you as part of an exercise without introducing you to undefined behavior and without explaining you `static_cast` in all details, you need to complain

Comment: In practice undefined behavior tends to bite most hard and ridiculously insulting manner when your boss is demonstrating it to investors.

Comment: Undefined Behavior Sanitizer finds a problem with this code: https://godbolt.org/z/9cz37hEPG (I've fixed other issues not related to a question).

Comment: "But if you run the code the output is always the same" why do you think it should produce different output every time? There are some myths about garbage or randomness related to undefined behavior, but they are mostly really just myths. UB has nothing to do with randomness and "garbage" is also the wrong term in this context.

Comment: "the output is always the same" until one day it is not.

Answer (score 2):

The cast does not "work". You pretend to have a pointer to an instance of `C` but the pointer does not point to an instance of `C`. Using that pointer to call a method is undefined.

Your code has undefined behavior. Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior and there are no restrictions on the compilers output. The output of this code could be anything.

PS: You should use the `override` specifier when overriding virtual methods. In this code it looks like you wanted `C::f` to override `A::f`, but it does not, and this will become apparent when you use `override`.

PS2: Calling a non-static method on a pointer of wrong type can sometimes appear to work when the method is not actually using `this`. Thats why you see "ok" output. However, that does not make it less wrong.